# JavaScript Phone Number Validation (rejecting inputs with alpha characters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I'm creating simple form validation that excludes any entries that have a letter in them (basically anything from a-z or A-Z).

This is what I am currently using but my script only rejects anything that isn't 0-9. which will reject periods, brackets and dashes which I want to validate.

```
var numericReg = /^\d*[0-9](|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$/;
    if(number != "" && !numericReg.test(number)) {
    return false;
```

How can I check for letters only?

Another way to do this would be to only accept inputs that have numbers 0-9, and the following characters: ".", "-", "(", ")"

Comment: What's the problem with only making sure someone inputed a value? Whats to say someone wouldn't type in "Cell: #555-555(5005)"

Comment: What if someone types their email address in there by accident? Then my data structure will be all fudged up!!

Comment: What about "1-800-MATTRES"? That's a valid phone number, no? :-D

Comment: In this case it's a contact form for a doctor's office so I'm fine with only accepting numerical phone numbers. I understand your arguments guys but validation has its place

Comment: A test for just letters is: `var hasAlpha = /[a-z]/i.test(s);`

Comment: True, that's what server side validation is for. Javascript is for basic testing. If you're data structures are based on something exact then you do that "hardcore requirement" testing after javascript is done. Either way I should have answered your question :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two regular expressions for you to try.  The first matches strings that only contain the characters you specified.  The second matches strings that contain no letters a-z or A-Z:

```
var isPhoneChar = /^[-.() \d]+$/;
var isNonAlpha = /^[^a-z]+$/i;
```

Keep in mind, `isNonAlpha` won't protect against ñüṃȅɍǒǘṩ ȯẗḥḛṝ ḽëʈťĕřś‼

You may consider also allowing `x` for phone ex̲tensions and `+` for international dialing.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use this for just directly pulling the number out.

CoffeeScript:

```
console.log number.match ///

  # Match the start of the string.
  ^

  # Get the first 3 digits.
  \(?(?=\d{3})(\d{3})[).\-\s]*

  # Get the next 3 digits.
  (\d{3})[.\-\s]*

  # Get the last 4 digits
  (\d{4})

  # End of the number
  $

///
```

Javascript (or Node):

```
console.log(number.match(/^\(?(?=\d{3})(\d{3})[).\-\s]*(\d{3})[.\-\s]*(\d{4})$/));
```

Here are the test cases I ran in CoffeeScript to make sure it worked:

```
exports '1234567890'
exports '123 456 7890'

exports '123.456.7890'
exports '123 456.7890'
exports '123.456 7890'
exports '123456.7890'
exports '123.4567890'
exports '123456. 7890'

exports '123-456-7890'
exports '123 456-7890'
exports '123-456 7890'
exports '123456-7890'
exports '123-4567890'

exports '(123)456-7890'
exports '(123)4567890'
exports '(123) 4567890'
exports '(123)456 7890'
exports '(123) 456 7890'
exports '(123) 4567890'
```

And their output:

```
1234567890
[ '1234567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '1234567890' ]
123 456 7890
[ '123 456 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123 456 7890' ]
123.456.7890
[ '123.456.7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123.456.7890' ]
123 456.7890
[ '123 456.7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123 456.7890' ]
123.456 7890
[ '123.456 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123.456 7890' ]
123456.7890
[ '123456.7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123456.7890' ]
123.4567890
[ '123.4567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123.4567890' ]
123456. 7890
[ '123456. 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123456. 7890' ]
123-456-7890
[ '123-456-7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123-456-7890' ]
123 456-7890
[ '123 456-7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123 456-7890' ]
123-456 7890
[ '123-456 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123-456 7890' ]
123456-7890
[ '123456-7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123456-7890' ]
123-4567890
[ '123-4567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '123-4567890' ]
(123)456-7890
[ '(123)456-7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123)456-7890' ]
(123)4567890
[ '(123)4567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123)4567890' ]
(123) 4567890
[ '(123) 4567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123) 4567890' ]
(123)456 7890
[ '(123)456 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123)456 7890' ]
(123) 456 7890
[ '(123) 456 7890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123) 456 7890' ]
(123) 4567890
[ '(123) 4567890',
  '123',
  '456',
  '7890',
  index: 0,
  input: '(123) 4567890' ]
```

If `number.match` returns `null` with that code, then it's not a valid number. So that's an easy way to check, and then have the number parsed already.

If you ever want to allow `a-z`, just change all of the `\d` entries to `[\d\w]`. ([See this](https://gist.github.com/3815845))